# Can a website change Safari’s default search engine?

Tags: safari, security, search-engine

My child’s MacBook had it’s default search engine changed to Yahoo. I did not do this, my child did not intentionally do this.

So I see two possibilities.

1. My kid downloaded and excecuted an app that changed it. Meaning nefarious code left the sandbox.
2. A website popped up a request to change it, and he clicked yes. Meaning just the search engine got changed and otherwise all is well.

Any thoughts on possible ways it could have flipped to Yahoo would be appreciated